# angular2 project won't run

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, command-line-interface

I tried running my angular 2 project on my ubuntu machine and got this error. Weird thing is, it was working fine 5 minutes ago. In between, I ran another ionic2 project and now the angular one is giving the following error. Similar thing happened with me yesterday with another angular 2 project. I do have the latest version of node and npm.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-77-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user6/.npm/_logs/2017-05-31T08_12_03_705Z-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-77-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user6/.npm/_logs/2017-05-31T08_12_03_740Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you updated anything i.e. `npm`, `typescript` and currently which version you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were a couple of compile errors in the project`. Due to that the npm start command was not working. If you are having the same issue, solve the compiler errors, even temporarily, and then try running the project.